# How to add video/stream to the Grafana dashboard?

Tags: grafana

I'm using the Grafana for monitoring time series data, now I want to add a camera or video/stream on a Grafana dashboard.

Is there any way or any plugin to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML panel - include your camera video (player) there

Comment: Can you more explain? where is HTML panel?

Comment: text panel with mode: html - http://docs.grafana.org/features/panels/text/

Comment: Thank you, +1, can we use css also?

Comment: Yes, you can write own css, js there as well

Comment: Check out this GitHub repo: https://github.com/cxnturi0n/grafana-livecamera-rtsp-webrtc